# python code through cron job not running

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I am trying to run a python3 script to check email for a certain condition, every day at a certain time.

I can see crontab invokes the commands, but the scripts does not give me the result I need, I.e. doesn't seem to run. I can see the cron execution in the syslog:

> Aug  3 16:25:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[4597]: (pi) CMD (cd /home/pi/pythonscripts )
>
> Aug  3 16:25:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[4598]: (pi) CMD (sudo python3 dfj_gmail_test_v1g.py > /home/pi/pythonscripts/cronlog.log)
>
> Aug  3 16:25:02 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[4595]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

The python script need to run, check gmail and if a certain email is found with a certain subject, it should turn on a LED through GPIO on my raspberry, it more a test for me than anything else. If I run the script from the command line itself (using the lines as in my crontab,) the script does the check and light the led. so the script itself is good. Any ideas on how to get more info on why the python script doesnt work through cron?

If need I can add the python 3 code

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two different cron jobs, one doing

```
cd /home/pi/pythonscripts
```

and the other

```
sudo python3 dfj_gmail_test_v1g.py > /home/pi/pythonscripts/cronlog.log
```

Those are independent jobs, the first one won't affect the second one, so the working directory for the second job will not be changed and the script will not be found. If you want this to work, you need to use a single command for both, e.g:

```
cd /home/pi/pythonscripts && sudo python3 dfj_gmail_test_v1g.py > /home/pi/pythonscripts/cronlog.log
```

Or give the fully qualified path to the python file if the working directory doesn't really matter:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/pythonscripts/dfj_gmail_test_v1g.py
```

Also, instad of using `sudo` from a crontab, consider using the root user's contab directly. And you should redirect stderr *and* stdout to your logfile, that will give your more detailled output in case of an error, e.g.:

```
... > /home/pi/pythonscripts/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

Or install a [MTA](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mail-transport-agent), then the output of cront jobs will be sent to the owner as email.

Comment: that is good advice. Is there a way that I can have the same cron execution run at say 1 minute intervals, rather then a set time?

Comment: Yes, you can specify a interval using `/interval`, e.g. `*/1 * * * *` would execute a cronjob every minute. See the [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html#EXAMPLE_CRON_FILE) manpages for more examples.